# How can mininet support openflow 1.3 completely?

Tags: mininet

As we know,the mininet ISO can not support openflow 1.3 protocols completely.So I want to set up the environment which mininet can support openflow 1.3 protocols,how can I do?

Answer (score 1):

From the Mininet FAQ:

"Recently, install.sh was updated to optionally install the CPqD version of the OpenFlow reference implementation and NOX classic, both of which support OpenFlow 1.3."

https://github.com/mininet/mininet/wiki/FAQ#openflow-switches